# How can I get the length of repeating decimal?

Tags: python, algorithm

I got an interview and the question is how to get the length of repeating decimal?

For example

```
1/3=0.3333..., it returns 1,
5/7=0.7142857142857143, it returns 6, since 714285 is the repeating decimal.
1/15=0.066666666666666, it returns 1.
17/150=0.11333333333333333, it returns 1. since 3 is the repeating decimal.
```

And I have tried to write a code

```py
def solution(a, b):
    n = a % b
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    mem = []
    n *= 10

    while True:
        n = n % b
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        if n in mem:
            i = mem.index(n)
            return len(mem[i:])
        else:
            mem.append(n)
        n *= 10
```

However, my code can't pass all tests. And it's time complexity is O(n*logn). How can I improve that and make its time complexity O(n)?

Comment: Looks OK to me on first glance. Which tests are failing?

Comment: for example 29/39916801. it will take a long time to get the result.

Comment: Ok, but it will eventually give the correct result, unless it runs out of memory first.

Comment: @AlexanderYau so the problem is that you want a faster algorithm, not that the one you have is not producing the correct result. Right?

Comment: @gsamaras. I am not sure my code is right. And it's really time-consuming given some large numbers.

Comment: This may be interesting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377683/length-of-period-of-decimal-expansion-of-a-fraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the proper way is to follow the math stack exchange link suggested by @Henry. But concerning your code here's my optimized version of it. The key point here is to use dictionary instead of array - the `in` operation is much faster in this case.

```
def solution(a, b):
    n = a % b
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    mem = {}
    n *= 10
    pos = 0

    while True:
        pos += 1
        n = n % b
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        if n in mem:
            i = mem[n]
            return pos - i
        else:
            mem[n] = pos
        n *= 10
```

On my computer for 29/39916801 this code finishes calculations in several seconds.

Comment: Very concise answer, I even forgot to take positions into consideration. Anyway, thank you!